# Storing dates in a single column in sql by transpose?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a single column that has a list of dates for the ends of various months plus today's date. So far I have:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '7/1/2016';  
SELECT 
CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
,EOMONTH ( @date, 1 ) 
,EOMONTH (@date, 2)  
,EOMONTH (@date, 3)  
,EOMONTH (@date, 4)  
,EOMONTH (@date, 5)  
,EOMONTH (@date, 6)  
,EOMONTH (@date, 7)  
,EOMONTH (@date, 8)  
,EOMONTH (@date, 9)  
,EOMONTH (@date, 10)
,EOMONTH (@date, 11)
,EOMONTH (@date, 12) ;  
GO
```

But that gives me an output where each result is a new column. Is there a way to transpose this output so it's just one column and each new result is a new row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I would just use `VALUES`.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2016-07-01';

SELECT  v.*
FROM (VALUES (@date),
             (EOMONTH(@date, 1)) ,
             (EOMONTH(@date, 2)), 
             (EOMONTH(@date, 3)), 
             (EOMONTH(@date, 4)),
             (EOMONTH(@date, 5)),
             (EOMONTH(@date, 6)),
             (EOMONTH(@date, 7)),
             (EOMONTH(@date, 8)),
             (EOMONTH(@date, 9)),
             (EOMONTH(@date, 10)),
             (EOMONTH(@date, 11)),
             (EOMONTH(@date, 12))
            ) v(dte);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using a recursive cte:

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '2016-07-01';  

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 As n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE n < 12
)
SELECT n, EOMONTH (@date, n)
FROM CTE
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/VNH8176)

Another, and probably better way, is to use a tally table.
If you don't know what a tally table is and why it's good for you, [read this article by Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

If you don't already have a tally table, create one:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Tally
    FROM sys.objects s1       
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2 
ALTER TABLE Tally ADD CONSTRAINT PK_NumbersTest PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Then your code is as simple as that:

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '2016-07-01';  

SELECT Number, EOMONTH (@date, Number)
FROM Tally
WHERE Number < 13
```

[Live demo for a tally table](http://rextester.com/ZZEW75435)

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
Declare @Date date = '7/1/2016';  
Declare @Mnth int  = 12     -- << Optional allows you to define the # of months

Select D = @Date
Union All
Select Top (@Mnth) EOMonth(@Date,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))) 
 From  master..spt_values    -- << Virtually any Table Will Do
```

**Returns**

```
D
2016-07-01
2016-08-31
2016-09-30
2016-10-31
2016-11-30
2016-12-31
2017-01-31
2017-02-28
2017-03-31
2017-04-30
2017-05-31
2017-06-30
2017-07-31
```